# Having Problems with the jQuery slider on my Financio WordPress Theme

Tags: wordpress

I'm using the financio Wordpress theme and I'm trying to update the images in the slider using some of the information in your video. For some reason my picture is off centered. Can you please take a look and see if you can tell me what I'm doing wrong? My website is www.brittanymcalpin.com